# How can PowerShell foreach possibly be failing with a null array in this code?

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

How can this powershell code possibly fail with 'Cannot index into a null array.'? It makes no sense to me at all. Surely $cloudPfx should be a non-null array?

```
$cloudPfx = @( "Foo.pfx", "Bar.pfx", $SSLCertFileName )
$cloudPfx | foreach {
    ## call some function...
    Save-Pfx "Foo\$_" (Join-Path $SomePath "Bar$_")
}

foreach : Cannot index into a null array.
At [that line]
+     $cloudPfx | foreach {
+                 ~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [ForEach-Object], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

Comment: It shouldn't, even if `$SSLCertFileName` is null.  Given that, there must be more to this code than what is posted.  What is in `$SSLCertFileName`, for example?

Comment: And, was the code copy/pasted by chance?  Are there any errant special characters appearing as spaces?

Comment: Try to use `foreach` statements instead of the cmdlet. I.e. change your code to `foreach($_ in $cloudPfx) {..}`. It will not solve your problem but you will hopefully get a better error message.

Comment: Also use this line instead of the original incorrect: `Save-Pfx "Foo\$_" (Join-Path $SomePath "Bar$_")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, by adding debug output statements - it turns out that the problem is really occurring inside the Save-Pfx function. It's just that the error presentation is completely wrong. (I think Roman probably suspected this, given that he suggested switching to foreach statements.)